# Adding my own lm-sensors sensor

Tags: c, linux, arduino, driver, kernel-module

I have a [source code](http://pastebin.com/dtx9T4sL) of Linux driver for my Arduino Uno. Arduino is programmed to send some numbers to the serial port. I can read these numbers in the userspace, using `read()` function on `/dev/ttyUSB0` device.

The question - is there a way to add arduino's numbers to lm-sensors output? Maybe add some code to the driver?(If you know it, please give a link/some manuals to read/any related information).

Thank you for suggestions.